# How to put a UIView all time on top screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiwindow

I will show a UITextView with all messages from the NSLog in my debug mode program. It work, but my problem is: I have to show it all times. So, how can I make my view to be showing all time in my program, look like the Status Bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

set the following

```
//Add the textView to the rootviewcontroller view
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 40);
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: great!! This is my mistake: rootViewController!!! I don't use it. I just get the top UIWindow but have to get the rootViewController. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work if a modal view controller is being presented.